# How do I set a background color for UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c

So I'm trying to set the background color of a subclass (I think it's called) and it won't work :( 
I have tried @interface BLAH BLAG BLAG : UIView 
But that won't work
I'm not trying to change the WHOLE UIView class just the one in the photo

Can someone please explain this?

photo ~> http://m.imgur.com/UgtSP9U

```
@interface IGFeedItemActionCell : UIView
@end

%hook IGFeedItemActionCell

- (void)setBackgroundColor:(UIColor *)color
{
  color = kDarkColor;
  return %orig;

}

%end
```

this doesnt change anything ;( I would be grateful if someone could fix this for me :) thank you

Comment: Just `self.backgroundColor = kDarkColor;` in `init` method or `awakeFromNib`

Comment: You probably want to call the super method. Not sure why you want to return a value in a void function. Also, you should use `override`, but don't see why you're overriding a function without extending the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

`UICollectionViewCell`s and `UITableViewCell`s are slightly more complex to alter, as they're comprised of several other views.  They also insert a selectedBackground view into selected cells in front of their normal backgroundView.

You can try changing the following cell properties:

```
self.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
self.selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```